# Javascript can't access keyboard event in an onblur function in IE 11 but not IE 9

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom

I'm currently running into an issue with trying to use the JavaScript event object. I have a Javascript function that waits for an onblur event and check to see if a the shiftkey is being pressed for an element on the document and do something if that's the case. The event.shiftKey works perfectly in IE 9 to detect if the shift key is pressed, but for the event object is different for an onblur event in IE 11 and it doesn't support the shiftKey event. When I did an alert on the event object, it says it was '[ojbect msEventObj]' in IE 9 and '[object focusEvent]' in IE 11. Is there a way to get around this difference between IE 9 and IE 11?

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
//using alert(event.shiftkey) gives me undefined in IE 11 because event
//is focusEvent object not msEventObj for some reason
element.onblur = function (){
    if (event.shiftKey == false) {
        alert('shift key was not pressed!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that event.shiftKey is not accessible from onblur - and you weren't passing the event to your event handler - I think you're trying to target onkeypress:

```
element.onkeypress = function (ex) { //pass event to handler ('ex' in this example)
            alert(ex.shiftKey); 
        }
```

This returns true when the shift key is being held down - false when it is not.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't define event, should be like this:

```
element.onblur = function (event){
    if (event.shiftKey == false) {
        alert('shift key was not pressed!');
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but event.shiftKey is always undefined.  Why would anyone hold shift when navigating from a control, anyway?

Comment: Also, as I said in my answer, 'shiftKey' is not a property of onblur event.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem for tab navigation.

```
element.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode !== 9) return;
    if (!event.shiftKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
        YOURTARGET.focus();
    }
});
```

Instead of a blur event, I listen for a keydown, check if it's tab, then run the code I want. It gives me access to `event.shiftKey`.